# possibilities with local variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Im wondering what are the possibilities with a local variable.
I know following :

1. You can get a value

   ```
   <select #selectField (change)="funtionBla(selectField.value)" 
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. You can call methodes of directives

   ```
    <button type="button" (click)="directiveBla.myFunction()"> test </button>
   ```

or HTML based

```
<video #movieplayer ...>
  <button (click)="movieplayer.play()">
</video>
```

But is there a way to change style things of a element VIA Local Variable or is it possible to append an element to a referenced one?

Comment: Doesn't look similar to me.

Comment: `ngStyles` and `ngClass` can make use of variables/properties to decide wether they get applied or not. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgStyle-directive.html#!#sts=ng-style%C2%A0bound%20to%C2%A0NgStyle.rawStyle and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html, as for the second answer I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, it seems to me that what you need is make a component and reuse it inside instead of append a referenced one.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a reference to elements with a local variable like

```
@ViewChild('selectField') someField;
```

it is also used for `DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation`

```
dcl.loadIntoLocation(DynamicElement, _elementRef, 'selectedField')
```